# AWS Rekognition image encode issue

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, webcam, encode, amazon-rekognition

I have a project to be finished and whenever the image is encoded into base64 as what AWS Rekognition docs told to do in order to obtain metadata.

`.getScreenshot()` return base64 of image that has captured.

Below is my code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import { creds } from "./secret";
import { Grid, Container, Button, Input } from "semantic-ui-react";

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: creds.accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: creds.secretAccessKey,
  region: "us-east-1"
});

const rekognition = new AWS.Rekognition({ apiVersion: "2016-06-27" });

class CameraComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      verificationFailed: "",
      verificationSucceed: "",
      faceId: "",
      fileName: ""
    };

    this.changeToFileName = this.changeToFileName.bind(this);
  }

  setRef = webcam => {
    this.webcam = webcam;
  };

  capture = () => {
    const image = this.webcam.getScreenshot().slice(23);
    console.log(image);

    const params = {
      SourceImage: {
        Bytes: image
      },
      TargetImage: {
        S3Object: {
          Bucket: "my-bucket",
          Name: "my-image.jpg"
        }
      },
      SimilarityThreshold: 0.0
    };

    rekognition.compareFaces(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);

      console.log(data);
    });
  };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your actual question? What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein issue is that even if the encoded base64 string passed in "Bytes" property as told, it is not returning data.

this.webcam.getScreenshot() returns base64 data from captured image.

Comment: Did you managed to fix this? Facing the same issue